# error: ‘NewSymbol’ is not a member of ‘v8::String’?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

Since the upgrade of NodeJS to 0.11.13, that integrates V8 engine 3.24.35.22 I get this error on some of C++ modules :

```
error: ‘NewSymbol’ is not a member of ‘v8::String’
```

What should I do instead of NewSymbol then ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

V8 has made some changes. I agree with the fact that you need to use NaN for a better V8 evolution. It's a nice macro framework.

`v8::String::New("test")` is converted into `NanSymbol("test")`.

But all new methods have been changed with a lovely template.

`NanNew<v8::Integer>(1)`, for instance, for an integer.

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS 0.11.13 make me cry.

I can propose [nan library](https://github.com/rvagg/nan). Some maintainers of NodeJS develops this lib. It is perfect.

I you need solution without deps, I recomend `String::newFromUtf8`.

Disclaimer: I hate deprecation in V8 library.

Answer (score 0):

V8's String API has been cleaned up a while ago to be more explicit about Unicode encodings, and to avoid confusion with the upcoming ES6 notion of symbols.

You now want to use [String::NewFromUtf8](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/include/v8.h#1778), String::NewFromOneByte, or String::NewFromTwoByte, with the respective arguments.